# Gnu-parallel resume when changing command

Tags: linux, gnu-parallel

When resuming a `parallel` command with `--resume`, is the command allowed to change?  In the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Progress-information) on `--resume`, it states that

> It it important that the input of the completed jobs is unchanged

but it doesn't mention if the command itself can change as long as the input doesn't change.

For example, if you start the command

`parallel --gnu -j8 --joblog log.txt ls ::: <inputs>`

and terminate it in the middle with Ctrl-C, can you resume with

`parallel --gnu -j8 --joblog log.txt --resume ls -l ::: <inputs>`

?

My use case is that my command is an exe that can take a long time for some inputs and I forgot to specify a flag on the exe to set the timeout.  I would like to restart with a timeout set on the exe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key part is:

```
As GNU parallel only looks at the sequence numbers
```

So you can basically change everything, but GNU Parallel will skip the jobs with the sequence numbers in the joblog.

Answer (score 0):

> skip the jobs with the sequence numbers

If you need to re-sort the input list, it is fairly easy to re-number the joblog:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import argparse


def pipe_lines(x) -> None:
    try:
        sys.stdout.writelines(x)
    except BrokenPipeError:
        sys.stdout = None
        sys.exit(141)


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("joblog", type=argparse.FileType("r"))
parser.add_argument("argsfile", nargs="?", type=argparse.FileType("r"), default=sys.stdin)
parser.add_argument("output_path", nargs="?")
args = parser.parse_args()

joblog = args.joblog.readlines()
args.joblog.close()

argsfile = args.argsfile.readlines()
args.argsfile.close()


new_joblog = ['Seq  Host    Starttime   JobRuntime  Send    Receive Exitval Signal  Command']
seq = 1
for argline in argsfile:
    for jobline in joblog:
        if argline.strip() in jobline:
            parts = jobline.split('\t')
            parts[0] = str(seq)
            new_joblog.append("\t".join(parts))
    seq += 1

if args.output_path:
    with open(args.output_path, "w") as output_fd:
        output_fd.writelines(new_joblog)
else:
    pipe_lines(new_joblog)
```

https://github.com/chapmanjacobd/computer/blob/main/bin/parallel_joblog_renumber.py